# Docker compose build with GitLab CI/CD throws botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I am trying to run an app using docker on a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The job is succeeding but I am facing an issue with boto3 (the AWS SDK) that is unable to locate the credentials.

I have placed the .aws folder in /root/ and also the config and credentials file used for that are having the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key. The dockerfile is copying those as well:

```
COPY ./.aws/ /root/
```

Now, once running it seems like boto is unable to find them.

Running the **aws configure list** returns a properly set profile. One thing I am not doing is setting a profile name and using the **[default]**.

Looking in the docs it should search in the .aws/credentials and .aws/config directory/files.

Now searching in various sources I am finding all about needing IAM task roles, some people are saying you do not need them, you need to set a profile name to make it work, it seems like I cannot find the solution.

Does anyone know what is the resolution here and faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLUTION:

So, I actually resolved this back then and it seems like this is a safe and easiest method to achieve this.

Using a password keeper package I am fetching the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from there and hardcoded AWS_REGION in the main script executing the app and then add them as environment variables once the container is running.

This works with just a few lines of code without any changes in the instance etc...

```
os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
os.environ["AWS_REGION"] = AWS_REGION
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your trailing slash on source is copying the contents rather than the folder in /root. You should try:

```
COPY ./.aws /root/
```

You can verify if they are where you expect them, by executing your container with `sh`.

```
docker exec -it your-image sh
ls -al ~/.aws/
```

This should show your files in the correct location.

---

All that said, I don't know how this affects your pipeline setup. I haven't used this CI tool much. However, if your tasks are run in a way that allows you to use task roles, then using roles is nearly always preferable to copying credentials into a container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this way. Regarding roles task roles: Are you meaning exactly this part: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#specify-task-iam-roles ? If so, is there a way to specify the task roles within the code or using the AWS CLI ?

Comment: The task role in that context is if the image is run as an ECS task. In that case by giving a task role, the scheduler ensures the running container has credentials for an iam role. It is like an instance profile for ec2. So if your pipeline schedules containers in ECS, maybe you could use that; it probably doesn't. There are many options, but copying creds into the container, as you are, should work.

Comment: Alright, so, I am not running it as an ECS task, but googling and searching for answers I have found one option that was related to configuring this one. Copying from: COPY ./.aws /root/ did not work too, throws same error. So know I have found that I can establish a session within my code, also still the same happening. Next one will be creating a user in docker to copy the folder to him (no idea if this makes any difference than the current one), IAM task roles next and then also the ECS task if this will not work. Seems like its not exactly working as described in docs searching for creds.

Comment: Did you docker exec into your container and verify the files are where they should be? You should be able to, if you have awscli in your container, do `aws sts get-caller-identity` to verify the credential resolution.